# How to set value from view into js

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to get the value of the selected option in javascript from view, does anyone know how to get the selected value or text, please tell how to write a function for it.

here the screenshot:
[Respondent page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppWJr.png)
. From this screenshot i want choose the "Period Name" will automatically corresponding value out of his chosen period on "Group Name".

Here the view page create.cshtml

```
<a href="#" class="button-blue button-text a-button" id="lnkAddResp" style="width:100px">@ViewRes.Language.multirater_respondent_add</a>
                    @foreach (var p in ViewBag.surveygroups)
                    {           
                                <input type="hidden" class="hiddenSurveyGroups" name="hiddenSurveyGroups" id="surveygroups" value="@p.Value" />
                    }
```

Controller page:

```
public ActionResult Create(int PeriodID = 0)
    {

        var ParentQry = from d in db.Periods
                        join sc in db.MultiRaterSurveyPeriods on d.PeriodID equals sc.PeriodID
                        where d.StartDate < DateTime.Now && d.EndDate > DateTime.Now && sc.StartDate < DateTime.Now && sc.EndDate > DateTime.Now
                        orderby d.PeriodID
                        select new {PeriodID = sc.MultiRaterSurveyPeriodID, PeriodName = d.PeriodName };

        var GroupResp = from d in db.MultiRaterSurveyGroups
                        join sc in db.RelationBetweenMRSPeriodMRSGroups on d.MultiRaterSurveyGroupID equals sc.MultiRaterSurveyGroupID
                        where d.StartDate < DateTime.Now && d.EndDate > DateTime.Now && sc.StartDate < DateTime.Now && sc.EndDate > DateTime.Now
                        orderby d.MultiRaterSurveyGroupID
                        select new { MultiRaterSurveyGroupID = d.MultiRaterSurveyGroupID, MultiRaterSurveyGroupName = d.MultiRaterSurveyGroupName, MultiRaterSurveyPeriodID = sc.MultiRaterSurveyPeriodID };

        ViewBag.PeriodID = new SelectList(ParentQry, "PeriodID", "PeriodName");
        ViewBag.surveygroups = new SelectList(GroupResp, "MultiRaterSurveyGroupID", "MultiRaterSurveyGroupName");}
```

JS page: How to set here on js, to make value appear according as i choose for a certain period name?

```
var linkresp3 = location.href;
        if (linkresp3.indexOf('MultiRaterSurveyRespondent/Create') != -1) {
            var peridresp = $("#PeriodID").val();
            var selectsurveygroups = $("#surveygroups").val('p.Value');
            var groupname = $("#GroupName_" + k);
            $(groupname).empty().append($('<select id="surveygroups" name="surveygroups"><option value="0" selected="selected">----- select -----</option><option value="' + $("#surveygroups").val() + '"</option></select>'));
            var opts = selectsurveygroups.filter(".Group" + peridresp);
            $.each(opts, function (i, j) {
            $(j).appendTo('#GroupName_' + k);
            });
            $("#GroupName_" + k).val(groupname);
```

Example: pick 2015 will appear: A, B, C and pick 2016 only appear B, B, D (was already been set on DB)

Comment: `$('#select_list_id').find('option:selected')` will give you selected option.

Comment: Agree with Akshay, but you will need .val() on the end to get the value assigned to the option.